# Sorting elements into k subarrays

Tags: sorting, counting, radix-sort

> Given are $n$ integer numbers in the range $0$ to $5n$.
>
> A SubSort algorithm organizes the numbers into $k=n/100$ sets,
> $s_{1}$, …, $s_{k}$ , each containing $100$ numbers, such that the
> following conditions hold:
>
> i. In each set, $_{}$, the 100 numbers are not necessarily sorted.
>
> ii. All numbers in set $_{}$ are smaller than all numbers in
> $_{}$, if and only if $ < $.
>
> Can the worst case time complexity of SubSort algorithm be $O(n)$?

This is my solution for the problem:

We can insert all elements into an array A, and as all elements are integers in the range of $[0,5n]$ we can use CountingSort to sort the array. This will cost us $O(n)$ time in the worst case.

Now we can create $k$ new arrays $s_{i},...,s_{k}$ and copy the first 100 elements into array $s_{i}$ and for every i<j≤k we copy all elements from $A[(j*100)-((j-1)*100)+1]$ to $A[j*100]$ to $s_{j}$. This will cost us an additional $O(n)$ time in the worst case.

In total we have $O(n)+O(n)∈O(n)$ time complexity in the worst case.

The official solution is below:

> We can sort all numbers and then split them into sets of 100 (each set
> will be sorted as well, although not requested). The sorting of all
> the elements will be linear since all numbers are integers in the
> range 0 to  5 , and we can use radix sort in the following manner:
> Each number k is represented using base n by 6 integer keys,  , 0
> ≤  ≤ 5. That is a key k = 0 + 1 + 2 2+ . . 5 5 . Then
> we can sort the set of keys using counting sort.

I don't quiet understand what they did with the change of base and how it helps them and I wondered if maybe someone can shed some light on why their solution works, and if mine does.

Comment: Are you sure that the upper bound on the value of the input elements is $5n$ and not $n^5$?

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @D.W. This is an exam question written by my professor, I'm sure she won't mind.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the upper bound on the maximum value of the $n$ input elements is $5n$ (as written in the question) then your solution works. Their solution works too but it is overcomplicated.

If the maximum value of the $n$ input elements is at most $n^5$, then your solution would require time $\Omega(n^5)$.

In general, if all $n$ input element are written in base $k$ (where $k$ fits in a [constant number of] memory word[s]) and are between $0$ and $k^m -1$, Radix sort takes at most $m$ iterations, each of which requires $O(n)$ time.

They chose $k=n$, so that $m \le 6$ (since $n^m - 1 \le n^5$ is equivalent to $m \le \log_n (1+ n^5)$ and $\log_n (1+ n^5) \le 1 + \log_n n^5 = 1+5$). The overall time spent is then $O(m \cdot n) = O(n)$.